# Shell script - set autofilter on a existing xls-file

Tags: powershell, shell, cmd, window

I want to set the filters on an existing .xls-file by running a shell script from the command line.

```
powershell -c "$excelObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;$excelWorkBook = $excelObj.Workbooks.Open(\"C:\Users\Desktop\Papierkorb\Test\test2.xlsx\");$excelWorkSheet = $excelObj.WorkSheets.item(\"Sheet1\");$excelWorkSheet.activate();$headerRange = $excelWorkSheet.Range(\"A1\",\"A1\").AutoFilter() | Out-Null;$excelWorkBook.Save();$excelWorkBook.Close();$excelObj.Quit()"
```

I am getting an error message:

> Unable to get the AutoFilter property of the Range class

At line:1 char:231

I tried several adaptions with the Range, but could not fix it. 
Thanks for your help,

Comment: You are trying to set autoFilter on a range with one cell (A1..A1). Can you extend the range to cover multiple cells and see if ti works ?

Comment: It gives unfortunatly the same error with all combinations like $headerRange = $excelWorkSheet.Range(\"A1\",\"Z1\")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to set AutoFilter on a range without data.

Try to put some text into cell "A1" in the test2.xlsx file (either using Excel, or problematically with PowerShell, example below). You can even put empty string `''`.

The following works for me.

```
$excelObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;$excelWorkBook = $excelObj.Workbooks.Open("d:\temp\test2.xlsx");
$excelWorkSheet = $excelObj.WorkSheets.item("Sheet1");
$excelWorkSheet.activate();
$headerRange = $excelWorkSheet.Range("A5","A5") ;
$headerRange.Item(1,1) = 'Something'
$headerRange.AutoFilter() ;
#$headerRange.AutoFilter() | Out-Null;
$excelWorkBook.Save();
$excelWorkBook.Close();
$excelObj.Quit()
```

Comment: I changed the code a bit and it is not throwing an error. I can not see the changes in the file, since it is locked by my user. ```powershell -c "$excelObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;$excelWorkBook = $excelObj.Workbooks.Open(\"C:\Users\Desktop\Papierkorb\Test\test.xlsx\");$excelWorkSheet = $excelObj.WorkSheets.item(\"Sheet1\");$excelWorkSheet.activate();$headerRange = $excelWorkSheet.Range(\"A1\",\"A1\") ;$headerRange.Item(1,1) = 'Something';#$headerRange.AutoFilter() | Out-Null;$excelWorkBook.Save();$excelWorkBook.Close();$excelObj.Quit()" ```